# Ubuntu 18.04 and Background Rendering produces transparent image

Tags: rendering, command-line

So I upgraded my system from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. With that I had to upgrade Nvidia drivers from 384 to 390, and a reinstall of modprobe and cuda-toolkit. Blender works ok, GPU live rendering works, and final GPU rendering works in the GUI.

Now, I have figured that I can render a little faster if I drop into a `tty` (aka "close" the desktop) and do a background rendering from the console, giving 99% of the GPU power to Blender.

However, after waiting 3 hours, the output image is all transparent. A file that should be about a megabyte is only 14 kilobytes.

This is what I used to render the scene:

```
./blender -b "/home/edward/Projects/20180520-CC/Chapter01/001_Basement.blend" -o "//Page070.png" -f 18 |grep Remaining
```

The `grep` is there because I think the console output has slowed down in 18.04. It would take up to 20 seconds just to list all the objects used in the blend file, where as in 16.04 it would be closer to 10 seconds or less.

So, any ideas why the image is transparent when I do background rendering, but shows up fine when rendering in the GUI?

**EDIT** Decided to `>output` what Blender is saying to a text file (blind render) and left it alone for more than 3 hours. Had a look at the text file for any errors and found the following:

```
write exr tmp file, 2560x1440, /tmp/blender_xSVx3E/001_Basement.blend_cloth.qc_RenderLayer.exr
Fra:18 Mem:1177.66M (0.00M, Peak 1308.13M) | Time:00:00.24 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | cloth.qc, RenderLayer | Synchronizing object | Window Panel
...
Fra:18 Mem:5296.60M (0.00M, Peak 7712.33M) | Time:03:04:38.91 | Mem:8767.59M, Peak:8791.54M | cloth.qc, RenderLayer | Finished
read exr tmp file: /tmp/blender_xSVx3E/001_Basement.blend_cloth.qc_RenderLayer.exr
failed being read /tmp/blender_xSVx3E/001_Basement.blend_cloth.qc_RenderLayer.exr
cannot read: /tmp/blender_xSVx3E/001_Basement.blend_cloth.qc_RenderLayer.exr
```

This sounds like the file got corrupt, or Blender doesn't have read permission to `tmp`. This means that Compositing had nothing to work with, and so a blank image.

Comment: The following works for me: `blender --background file.blend --render-output //result --render-format PNG --use-extension 1 --render-frame 1`

Comment: Long switch names did not work.